# Failed to read S3TransferUtility please check your setup or awsconfiguration.json file

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I am a newbie using AWS sdk for video transfer.But i am getting the error "Failed to read S3TransferUtility please check your setup or awsconfiguration.json file". Here is my code.

In my manifest file i have

```
<service android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService" android:enabled="true" />
```

In my oncreate i am doing this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_post);

    AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this).execute();

transferUtility =
                TransferUtility.builder()
                        .context(this)
                        .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
                        .s3Client(new AmazonS3Client(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider()))
                        .build();

}
```

The exception comes at .build. I debugged the code and it picks up the config file located at in folder perfectly cause i can see the data in debug but i think the transferutility.TransferService is not running. Can someone please help. Thanx

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Sorry bro, can't remember. I think i found a work around but don't remember now.

Comment: there was some permission problem i think

Comment: Hi @Syed I figured it out..Needed to add this following block to "awsconfiguration.json" file."

"S3TransferUtility": {
    "Default": {
      "Bucket": "<bucket_name>",
      "Region": "<region>"
    }
  }

Comment: @SyedMuhammadOan , My answer is working :) and got the highest ranking. Do you mind accept it as an answer to your question?

Answer (score 7):

For some reason the auto generated "awsconfiguration" file doesn't include the most important section called "**S3TransferUtility**". So you have to add it manually.
Your "awsconfiguration.json" file should look something like this:

```
{
  "UserAgent": "MobileHub/1.0",
  "Version": "1.0",
  "CredentialsProvider": {
"CognitoIdentity": {
  "Default": {
    "PoolId": "us-east-1:<RANDOM-GUID>",
    "Region": "us-east-1"
  }
}
  },
  "IdentityManager": {
    "Default": {}
  },
  "PinpointAnalytics": {
    "Default": {
      "AppId": "<UNIQUE ID>",
      "Region": "us-east-1"
    }
  },
  "PinpointTargeting": {
    "Default": {
      "Region": "us-east-1"
    }
  },
  "S3TransferUtility": {
    "Default": {
      "Bucket": "<YOUR BUCKET NAME>",
      "Region": "us-east-1"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In my **awsconfiguration.json**  i add   below lines then it's started working

```
  "S3TransferUtility": {
    "Default": {
      "Bucket": "<YOUR BUCKET NAME>",
      "Region": "us-east-1"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Add awsconfiguration.json on your project and change pool id and region attributes. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-cognito-integrate-an-existing-identity-pool.html#create-the-awsconfiguration-json-file).